# python-sorting list containing dict(a,b,c as keys)

Tags: python, sorting

i'm trying to sort this list containing dict

```
import pap4globals
data_list_dict1=[{'a':1, 'b':4, 'c':2},
                {'a':9, 'b':3,'c':2},
                {'a':2,'b':10,'c':1}]

def sort1(data,rev=False):
    if rev==False:
        temp=0
        for i in range(0,len(data_list_dict1)-1):
            startIndex=len(data_list_dict1)-1
            for j in range(len(data_list_dict1[i]-2,i-1,-1)):
                if data_list_dict1[j]<data_list_dict1[startIndex]:
                    startIndex=j
            temp=data_list_dict1[i]
            data_list_dict1[i]=data_list_dict1[startIndex]
            data_list_dict1[startIndex]=temp
        return temp.append(pap4globals.data_list_dict)

    if rev==True:
        temp=0
        for i in range(0,len(data_list_dict1)-1):
            startIndex=len(data_list_dict1)-1
            for j in range(len(data_list_dict1[i]-2,i-1,-1)):
                if data_list_dict1[j]>data_list_dict1[startIndex]:
                    startIndex=j
            temp=data_list_dict1[i]
            data_list_dict1[i]=data_list_dict1[startIndex]
            data_list_dict1[startIndex]=temp
        return temp.append(pap4globals.data_list_dict)
```

where the pap4globals

```
import os

def initiate():
    global data_list_dict
    data_list_dict=[]
```

tried to call the function on pap4drv.py

```
import os
import pap4globals
from pap4lib import *
def main():
    pap4globals.initiate()
    sort1(pap4globals.data_list_dict,False)
    print(pap4globals.data_list_dict)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

then i got error message

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'dict' and 'int'
```

still confused at which replacement that suit my purpose. 
is it only on the following line?

```
for j in range(len(data_list_dict1[i]-2,i-1,-1)):
```

p.s. : my lecturer won't allow us to use built-in function in python

Comment: On which line does the error appear?

Comment: You can cut `sort1` in half by adding `op = operator.gt if rev else operator.lt` as the first line, then using `if op(data_list_dict1[j], data_list_dict1[startIndex]):` in the body.

Comment: The `-2` is taken from a dictionary at index`I`

Comment: You have two issues, which should be handled separately. A) how do I sort a list, and B) how do I compare two instances that are like this ...

Answer (score 1):

The line:

```
for j in range(len(data_list_dict1[i]-2,i-1,-1)):
```

should change to

```
for j in range(len(data_list_dict1[i])-2,i-1,-1):
```

Now there is an error because `len` has too many arguments.

Secondly, the following line

```
if data_list_dict1[j] < data_list_dict1[startIndex]:
```

will throw an error because `<` is not supported between 2 dictionaries.

On what exactly you want to sort?

-------------------------------------------------------------- EDIT -------------------------------------------------------------
I adapted your function. This should work:

```
def sort1(data,rev=False):
    if rev==False:
        for letter in data_list_dict1[0]: #First the A, then the B

            for i in range(0, len(data_list_dict1) - 1):
                currSmallestIndex = i
                for  j in range(i + 1, len(data_list_dict1)):
                    if (data_list_dict1[j][letter] < data_list_dict1[currSmallestIndex][letter]):
                        currSmallestIndex = j

                temp=data_list_dict1[i][letter]
                data_list_dict1[i][letter]=data_list_dict1[currSmallestIndex][letter]
                data_list_dict1[currSmallestIndex][letter]=temp
```

Comment: im trying to sort the value of a,b,and c. as you can see, 'a' has 3 value,each in different row, so does the 'b' and 'c'. and yeah,i copied the code from my previous experiment(sorting list)

Comment: Can you specify how you want your "data_list_dict1" to look like after sorting?

Comment: @KennyOstrom answered why there is an error. But there are some other things wrong as well

Comment: for the false condition, it should be something like this                                                             [{ 'a':1, 'b':3, 'c':1},
 { 'a':2,  'b':4, 'c':2},
 { 'a':9, 'b':10, 'c':2}]

Comment: for the true condition,just the reverse from false condition(the first condition sort the dict on ascending order,the second sort it on descending)

Comment: I made it work for the True condition in the answer above. The false condition you can implement yourself just reversing the list ;)

Comment: did temp=0 still used to? and how do i fill the data_list_dict? use the .append() ? anyway,thanks for patiently answering my question. it's 3.37am here. somehow i amazed i still alive

Comment: Your welcome! Temp = 0 is not needed anymore.   You can write all your code in the same file and remove all your imports, put data_list_dict1=[{'a':1, 'b':4, 'c':2}, {'a':9, 'b':3,'c':2},         {'a':2,'b':10,'c':1}] as a global var, above. The function sort1, also doesn't need the 'data' parameter anymore but can directly acces data_list_dict1

Comment: does the function sort1 need to return value?

Comment: No, it adapts the global variable 'data_list_dict1'

Comment: I'll try it again. somehow i still got error on the previous attempt. sorry for this late reply.